# Parsing php data to get only individual data

Tags: php, mysql

How do I parse this data? 
This is a datetime that were from my database

```
2011-09-27 13:14:11
```

I want to get only the 13 14 and 11 separately.
the output should be:

```
13
14
11
```

Please be noted that this is a dynamic value
I could also get a datetime that has this value:
2011-09-27 1:12:00

How would I do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: do you need to parse in the sql query??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you've assigned `2011-09-27 13:14:11` from db table to variable named `$datetime`

```
$result =  strtotime($datetime);
$minute = date("i", $result );
$second = date("s",$result );
$hour = date("H", $result );
```

In your case `$hour` will be 13, `$minute` will be 14, `$second` will be 11. [More detailed in PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

*BTW*

if you want to get seperate year, month, day too, use following piece of code

```
$year = date("Y", $result );
$month = date("m",$result );
$day = date("d", $result );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class to make this happen

```
$date = new DateTime('2011-09-27 13:14:11');
printf("%s <br />", $date->format('H'));
printf("%s <br />", $date->format('i'));
printf("%s <br />", $date->format('s'));
// Outputs:
// 13
// 14
// 11
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the SQL query, you could simply do:

```
SELECT
    HOUR( `dateTimeColumn` ) AS `hours`,
    MINUTE( `dateTimeColumn`) AS `minutes`,
    SECOND( `dateTimeColumn` ) AS `seconds`,
    # etc...
FROM
    `yourTable`
# etc...
```

... thereby letting MySQL do the parsing, and access them in PHP with something like:

```
$row[ 'hours' ];
$row[ 'minutes' ];
$row[ 'seconds' ];
```